# Adobe Flash ActionScript 2.0 selected text in textbox

Tags: flash-cs3

How can I tell what text the user highlighted in an Input Text textbox?  I would like to mention that selectionBeginIndex and selectionEndIndex will not work and at this point I cannot upgrade the project to AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as2_components_help.pdf

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as2_components_reference.pdf

this is the component manual and has everything.

Also, here is the AS2 language ref:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as2_language_reference.pdf

This is what you need to quickly answer the question.